# Game server programming (reliable and unreliable communication)

Tags: .net, networking, tcp, udp, server

I'm currently developing a simple online-multiplayer game via .NET sockets in C#.

More precisely I'm trying to create the network communication structure around this game - not so much the game itself. For now I have a working HTTP-Server which handles basic requests, like "create a new game instance (party)", "join an existing party" etc.

This is working fine, but I don't really know how to handle communication inside a game instance. From my understanding there should be both, reliable communication and unreliable communication. Like sending a "kick player", "pause game", "get player list" request (reliable) and sending inputs, receiving snapshots (unreliable).

Does this mean it would make sense to have two seperate sockets (udp and tcp) running on different ports, so I actually have two servers to communicate with per game instance? Or is there a way to achieve both, guaranteed delivery and unreliable delivery via one single udp socket?

Note: *I'm not really aiming for ordered packet arriving, so reliable for me mainly means making sure the packet actually reaches its destination*

Note2: *I don't really want to bother the http server with this game-instance specific reliable stuff, in my opinion it would be nicer if the game instances could handle this by themselves*

I saw [This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083698/using-tcp-and-udp-for-java-game) being similar, but the accepted answer does not really help me. My questing regarding the answer there is: How is it possible to combine reliable and unreliable communication via .NET sockets in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to use separate ports - indeed it would be an advantage to only use one to simplify whatever instructions your end users would need for opening the inbound ports on their routers if necessary.

Check out libenet (http://enet.bespin.org) for an open source library that takes care of multiple connections over one port. It supports both guaranteed sequenced and unreliable streams.

Comment: This looks nice! These multiple ports that are used per game instance in my "approach" is also what bothers me most.
So I guess the way to go is to use just one UDP socket and build a custom TCP-like structure on top of it either by implementing it by hand or using a library. This way the user could decide whether to send the Datagram reliably or not.